# Json decoding arrays

Tags: arrays, json

I have decoded a json array in a php script (see below)

I can access those values not contained in the items array quite easily:

['order']['shippingOption']['shippingRate']

['order']['subtotal']

but can't figure out how to access the values like productSku, weight in the "items" array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
{

"order":{
"total":245.4,
"shippingOption":{
"shippingRate":5.4,
"shippingMethodId":"15367-1365940349119",
"estimatedTransitTime":"1",
"shippingMethodName":"Courier (Fastway)",
"type":""

},
"ticket":0,
"usdTotal":0,
"paymentParams":{
"map":{
}
},
"paymentStatus":"INCOMPLETE",
"volumeDiscount":0,
"subtotal":240,
"couponDiscount":0,
"tax":0,
"items":[
{
"relatedProducts":{
"productIds":"",
"relatedCategory":{
"enabled":false,
"categoryID":0,
"quantity":1
}
},
"weight":500,
"quantityInStock":0,
"tangible":true,
"ownerId":658087,
"wholesalePrices":{
},
"digital":false,
"id":0,
"fileKeys":[],
"shipping":5.4,
"imageId":94075362,
"productSku":"00247",
```

Comment: You can just `foreach` over them, or access them by indexes, such as `$obj->items[0]->enabled`.

Comment: Post a valid JSON, which can pass the JSON validator test, please!

Comment: Noob UnChained - the valid JSON is VERY long, that is why I never posted it in full. You can access it here: [link](http://www.farmboutique.com/process1.php)

Comment: The link shows something that is not JSON...

Comment: neutrino - I think it is now, I had decoded it.

Comment: Niels - thanks for the info, I have now managed to work it using the info you gave me.